# Codeigniter index page not visible

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I am shifting my codeigniter project from my windows to Ubuntu(Guest OS on Virtual Box) I have created a virtual host in apache2(Ubuntu) which is up and running. When I try to run the mysite.lo instead of the actual `index.php of my project` the browser displays the default index.php page of codeigniter package which looks like this.

```
Copied some parts of the index.php page displayed by the browser.


  <?php

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * You can load different configurations depending on your
 * current environment. Setting the environment also influences
 * things like logging and error reporting.
 *
 * This can be set to anything, but default usage is:
 *
 *     development
 *     testing
 *     production
 *
 * NOTE: If you change these, also change the error_reporting() code below
 *
 */
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
/*
```

Which is not the page that I want to display. I have set up my `base url` as shown below

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysite.lo';
```

My .htaccess file

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteBase /
       //tried this way as well RewriteBase /mysite.lo/ 
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And the settings in mysite.lo/config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "login";
$route['404_override'] = 'login/home';
```

Will be grateful if someone can help me solve the problem. Regards

Comment: Hi. did you install php?

Comment: Really stupid of me. Thank you @elddenmedio

Comment: Hi @karma, keep me informed if that was the solution

Comment: Yes! @elddenmedio that was the solution. After I installed php things worked. I did do php --var in my ubuntu terminal it said php 5.xx lubuntu xx (which I do not remember properly) so thought PHP was installed. Thanks for your response.